# Extract Liquid macro with quotes from anchor elements using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, liquid

I'm working on a service that lets people render their HTML pages using the Liquid templating engine, and I want to extract any `href`s from any `a` elements, so we can run stats on the clicked links later.

Using BeautifulSoup, I came up with something like this. The idea is to add the URL-encoded value to the `data-original-macro`attribute if it's a Liquid macro in the `href` attribute

```py
def add_original_macro_to_links(html: str) -> str:
    html_tree = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")

    for a in html_tree.find_all("a"):
        href = a.get("href")
        print(href)
        if not href or not re.match(r"{{.+}}", href):
            continue

        a["data-original-macro"] = parse.quote(href)

    return str(html_tree).strip()
```

This works for most cases, except when a macro has a `"` character in it, like this example:

```html
<ul>
{%- for person in people %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{person | prepend: "http://example.com/"}}">
      {{ person | capitalize }}
    </a>
  </li>
{%- endfor%}
</ul>
```

In this case, BeautifulSoup will parse the `a` element as this:
`<a href="{{person | prepend: " http:="">{{ person | capitalize }}</a>`, which doesn't work for my purposes.

My question is, is there some way to correctly extract the href consistently? Worst case I may just ignore this case, since I'm thinking only the odd customer will use this format, as it's not in our website's default set of macros.

Comment: Is there a URL with an example of these macros?

Comment: I haven't run into any real world examples because this code hasn't actually been deployed yet, but the question itself has an example `a` tag with a problematic liquid macro in the `href` attribute: `{{person | prepend: "http://example.com/"}}`

Comment: And a working test case (html) ?